# using setTimeout in for loop

Tags: javascript, node.js, settimeout

I am trying write a function which print 5 wait to 1 sec and print number 4 wait for 2 secs and print number 3 wait for 3 secs and so on

I wrote this function :

```
for(let i=5;i>0;i--){
   setTimeout(()=>{
   let localTime = new Date().toLocaleString();
    console.log(`${i} - ${localTime}`)
  },5-i*1000);
}
```

And this prints:

```
'5 - 10/30/2019, 11:10:17 AM'
'4 - 10/30/2019, 11:10:17 AM'
'3 - 10/30/2019, 11:10:17 AM'
'2 - 10/30/2019, 11:10:17 AM'
'1 - 10/30/2019, 11:10:17 AM'
```

I wrote these set of statements :

```
console.log(new Date().toLocaleString());

 setTimeout(()=>{
  let localTime = new Date().toLocaleString();
    console.log(`${5} - ${localTime}`)
},1000)

setTimeout(()=>{
  let localTime = new Date().toLocaleString();
    console.log(`${4} - ${localTime}`)
},2*1000)

setTimeout(()=>{
  let localTime = new Date().toLocaleString();
    console.log(`${3} - ${localTime}`)
},3*1000)
setTimeout(()=>{
  let localTime = new Date().toLocaleString();
    console.log(`${2} - ${localTime}`)
},4*1000)
setTimeout(()=>{
  let localTime = new Date().toLocaleString();
    console.log(`${1} - ${localTime}`)
},5*1000)
```

And these print:

```
'10/30/2019, 11:13:45 AM'
'5 - 10/30/2019, 11:13:46 AM'
'4 - 10/30/2019, 11:13:47 AM'
'3 - 10/30/2019, 11:13:48 AM'
'2 - 10/30/2019, 11:13:49 AM'
'1 - 10/30/2019, 11:13:50 AM'
```

The second set of statements are increasing the time by 1 sec but the set time out in for loop is not doing.

How to achieve the functionality and where am I going wrong?

Comment: I think setInterval is a better approach for you: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_setinterval.asp

Comment: ORDER OF OPERATIONS

Answer (score 2):

Order of operations

```
5 - 1 * 1000
5 - (1*1000)
5 - 1000
-995
```

It needs to have parenthesis

```
},(5-i) * 1000);
```

A better way without the for loop is just create a function and have the timer recursively call it until it is done.

```js
function countDown (max) {
   function execute () {
     let localTime = new Date().toLocaleString();
     console.log(`${max} - ${localTime}`)
     max -= 1
     if (max>0) window.setTimeout(execute, 1000)
   }
   execute()
}

countDown(5);
```

Comment: Guess downvoter thinks it should been closed and not answered. :)