# How to timeout with for loop for ajax request

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I use for loop with timeout to request ajax every 5 seconds

```
function req() {
  $.ajax({ .......
  })
}

for (var i = 4000; i <= 6000; i++) {

  setTimeout(function() {
    req(i)
  }, i * 5000);

}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [using setTimeout in for loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58629739/using-settimeout-in-for-loop)

Comment: What is the problem with your current code?

Comment: [setInterval](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/setInterval)?  `setInterval(req, 5000)` and skip the whole loop, which would pre-load your ajax requests, which sounds like a *bad idea*.   But use @mplungjan solution of starting a new one when, and only when, your first one finishes.  (if you must use polling at all, rather than something else like websockets)

Comment: It is not clear what you want. Every 5 seconds is not 4 to 6 seconds  -  please give more details

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can send the request after every `5s` using

```
time + time * (i - start)
```

```js
function req(s) {
  console.log("After " + s + "s");
  // $.ajax({.......})
}

const start = 4000,
  end = 6000,
  time = 5000;

for (let i = start; i <= end; i++) {
  setTimeout(function () {
    req((time + time * (i - start)) / 1000); // I've passed the time to track the passed seconds
  }, time + time * (i - start));
}
```

Comment: wow, it worked, thanks a lot <3

Answer (score 2):

Don't loop Ajax. If the server is overloaded, you will stack requests that will cancel each other

Instead do

```
function req() {
  $.ajax({ .......
    success: function() {
      setTimeout(req,5000)
    }
  })
}
```

If you want to send with 3 different intervals, you can do this

```
const timeouts = [4000,5000,6000];
let cnt = 0;
function req() {
  $.ajax({ .......
    success: function() {
      setTimeout(req,timouets[cnt]); // move this to an if to stop after 3 calls
      cnt++; if (cnt>= timeouts.length) {
        cnt = 0;
      }
    }
  })
}
```

Comment: in the request i need values 4000 - 6000 thats why i use it.

Comment: @YusufHR see update

Answer (score 0):

You can take it as creating a  series of time-lapsed requests via for loop.

```js
function req() {
   console.log('requested');
}

for (let i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
   setTimeout(req, i * 5000)   
}
```

However, such a series of requests can easily be achieved with `setInterval` too.

```js
function req(){
   console.log('requested');
}

const limit = 10;
let counter = 1;

let handler = setInterval(function(){
   
   req();
   
   counter++;
   
   if (counter >= limit)
      clearInterval(handler);
   
}, 5000)
```